# Git and ssh authorizating

Tags: git, ssh, github, rsa

I can't login to github with generated ssh-keys. I've followed this manual: http://help.github.com/linux-key-setup but at step:

> ssh git@github.com

I get:

> Agent admitted failure to sign using
>   the key. Permission denied
>   (publickey).

What's wroing? And, of course, I'm adding my own user email.

---

Tried dsa-key, the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [troubleshooting guide](http://github.com/guides/addressing-authentication-problems-with-ssh):

> Permission denied (publickey)
>
> This is usually caused when ssh cannot
>   find your keys. Make sure your key is
>   in the default location, ~/.ssh. If
>   you run ssh-keygen again and just
>   press enter at all 3 prompts it will
>   be placed here automatically. Then you
>   can add the contents of id_rsa.pub to
>   my github keys. If id_rsa.pub doesn’t
>   work try id_dsa.pub. You might need to
>   generate a new dsa key with ssh-keygen
>   -t dsa if you just have an rsa key.
>
> If you are still having problems and
>   none of the above worked, you may have
>   a blacklisted key from a debian
>   open-ssh bug. you should update
>   open-ssh and re-generate your keys.

So, just to check - are your keys available under ~/.ssh/ as id_rsa and id_rsa.pub or otherwise, are you specifying their use?

Comment: I've found that before posting here. Of course my keys are in ~/.ssh.

Comment: Excellent, then, are the perms of that dir set to 0600? Just running through things that might be wrong because it looks like ssh-agent or ssh isn't picking up your keys.

Answer (score 50):

I found this which helped me greatly http://playwithrubyandrails.blogspot.com/2011/04/process-for-deploying-app-on-heroku.html

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` solved my problem after generating the relevant keys

Comment: what does ssh-add do exactly?

Comment: @duckx it adds the id_rsa key to known hosts on your system. Have a look here https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add for more information on options etc...

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ No no no! Don't listen to jamesc on that one... The `ssh-add` asks you for your password and saves the decrypted private key in memory using the `ssh-agent` service. Then when you later try to use that same private key, the agent will provide it in clear. I do not know the exact functionality, I could imagine that the `ssh-agent` keeps the keys encrypted and decrypt them when needed. That is, it is likely to have a way to keep the keys in a somewhat safer manner than just ballantely in clear. The `known_hosts` is something else.

Answer (score 13):

After generating the ssh keys I executed the command listed below as suggested by jamesw.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I entered my password. Then retried to clone the heroku repository. This time it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is a ubuntu problem. Exporting "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0" solved the problem for me. More details can be found at - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/201786.

Comment: Thank you!  I'd followed so many different tips on how to generate SSH keys but it was this simple export that fixed it on Ubuntu.

Comment: My variable is set so: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. I would imagine that this would remove the ability of saving the key in `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get gitlab working thanks to this thread (I know that's not github).

I too found the answer by @jamesw to be correct.

I ended up having to delete my `known_hosts` file and recreate my ssh key with the same password as my gitlab account.

Then I did the `ssh-add` and did a `git push -u origin master`. Success!

Thanks for the help everyone.

**UPDATE:**
I decided to remake my ssh key without a password and ran into this error again.

This time, I was able to copy my old `known_hosts` to the new `.ssh/` and simply run the `ssh-add`.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs mainly due to the following reasons :

- The public and private key pair is wrong. You have to verify the key public key on the server/ your git account where you have placed the public key. Even a small space or tab will result in the error.
- If you are sure your public key is correct, then check the format of public key in your ~/.ssh folder in your machine. For openssh you cannot use a public key in puttygen format and visa-versa. To change the format you can use the following command using your private key

  $ ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa_com.pub
  $ ssh-keygen -i -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_com.pub > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- Finally check if you have added your keys to the ssh client in your  system. You can do so by using the following commands

  $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

  $ ssh-add

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ssh-agent` is per session (per terminal).  Use ssh agent manager like [keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/keychain/index.xml) (see its documentation on how to set it up) to have access via any session (from any term).

Answer (score 0):

Above Accepted  solution did not work for me, but this worked
http://ripan27.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/ssh-gitgithub-com-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key-permission-denied-publickey/

Answer (score 0):

I encounterded same error when I copied id_rsa and idrsa.pub from another os. These files were 644 permission. So I changed it to 600. the error was fixed.