# setting up git in a private server, it asks for git password

Tags: git, gitolite

I am setting up git in an ubuntu 12.10 VPS. This is my first time setting up a git repository so I am just a beginner, and I'm sure I'm missing some important stuff. I have executed the following commands in my server:

```
# apt-get install git-core
# git config --global user.name "Roberto"
# git config --global user.name "roberto@example.com"
# apt-get install gitolite
# adduser --system --gecos 'git version control' --shell /bin/bash --group --disabled-password --home /home/git git
# su git
$ echo "PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH" > ~/.bashrc
$ cd
$ gl-setup /tmp/roberto.pub
```

roberto.pub is my public certificate in my work machine. Then from that work machine, I have tried to clone the gitolite-admin repository, to manage the git server:

```
$ git clone git@vps:gitolite-admin.git
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
git@vps's password:
```

Which I have not even set! Shouldn't it be asking me for roberto's password instead?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`gl-setup` means old gitolite v2.
Don't. Just don't: it is so easy to get gitolite V3 and [all its nice features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309).

Clone somewhere the latest gitolite repo:

```
 git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
```

And carefully follow the [installation instructions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html) and [setup](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/setup.html).

```
 gitolite/install -to /your/path/to/gitolite/bin
 gitolite setup -pk roberto.pub
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have done as you said. I'm not getting any warning while configuring it. But when I try git clone ssh://git@vps/gitolite-admin.git, I am getting the error "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key". Then it's asking for git's password once again.

Comment: @sogeking then see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2546065/6309. And make sure your private key isn't passphrase-protected: let's make this work with a simple ssh config instead of having to deal with an ssh agent.

Comment: I am not getting the last error anymore, I have edited my .ssh/config to use the public key I specified. But now, it asks me for roberto's pass and afterwards it returns the following: "fatal: 'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: @sogeking an `.ssh/config` is meant to reference your *private* key, not your public one. See as an illustration http://stackoverflow.com/a/12998492/6309.

Answer (score 0):

`gitolite` works by having a single system user, and all users of the repositories connect there.

A password prompt when using a server with `gitolite` usually indicates some problem with the private key on the machine you are connecting from.

A couple of pointers:

- did the installation work? Check the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the `git` user on the server, does it contain your public key? If not, rerun the installation of gitolite (maybe try with the from source install as well)
- If the key is there, check if you are able to ssh to it `ssh -T git@vps` (`-T` disables ptty allocation, sometimes ssh doesn't work with gitolite). If yes, `git` is unable to access the private key.
- if you are not able to connect (or only git isn't able) check if your ssh-agent is working correctly. Also try and see if you are to connect to any user with pubkey auth that is not gitolite.

Comment: My public key is in .ssh/authorized_keys. Anyhow, ssh -T git@vps keeps on asking me for the password.

Comment: I can log in remotely as roberto through ssh, although not if I disable PasswordAuthentication on the server -Permission denied (publickey)-. I will try with a new pubkey.

Comment: A new key didn't work. 
$ git clone git@vps:gitolite-admin
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
roberto@vps's password: